# Mapping Excel sheet to XML Schema - using a column for multiple attributes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, xml

I have data like this in Excel:

[image: data]

I want to export XML using XML Maps feature like this instance, based on a schema that *cannot* be modified:

```
<someRootElement>
  <Foo Key1="A" Key2="Q">Cheese</Foo>
  <Foo Key1="L" Key2="Z">Westie</Foo>
  <Foo Key1="M" Key2="S">Fox</Foo>
  <Bar Key1="A" Key2="Q">Merlot</Bar>
  <Bar Key1="L" Key2="Z">Schnauzer</Bar>
  <Bar Key1="M" Key2="S">Wapapapapapapow</Bar>
</someRootElement>
```

However, when I try to add `Key1` and `Key2` to map to the appropriate attributes in *both `Foo` and `Bar`*, as soon as I try to map it a second time, I get this error:

[image: XML Maps error]

It seems like I would have to structure my data as follows, which is ridiculously redundant:

[image: updated]

Then I could map `Key1_Foo` to the `Key1` attribute of `Foo`, `Key1_Bar` to the `Key1` attribute of `Bar`, etc.

However, there is a 1:1 relationship in the number of rows for each of these, so it is much more concise in Excel to only give the key columns once.

**Why can't I map the same column to multiple elements? What is a good workaround?**

Comment: I don't know if a workaround for this exists aside from what you've done. You could automate the conversion from the first form to the second form with VBA, I guess? Maybe someone else has something.